# Change and read properties of objects in ConcurrentDictionary in thread safe manner

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, concurrentdictionary

I use `ConcurrentDictionary` to collect data in memory in web api application. Using api methods I add and update objects in `ConcurrentDictionary`. And there is background thread which analyze and clean up this dictionary based on object properties. Now I'm considering two approaches:

**1.** use lock on dictionary item in `updateValueFactory` in `AddOrUpdate` method, but question is how to read properties properly to be sure I have the latest version of it and that I'm not reading property in not stable state.

```
public class ThreadsafeService2
{
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, ThreadSafeItem2> _storage = 
        new ConcurrentDictionary<string, ThreadSafeItem2>();

    public void AddOrUpdate(string name)
    {
        var newVal = new ThreadSafeItem2();
        _storage.AddOrUpdate(name, newVal, (key, oldVal) =>
        {
            //use lock
            lock (oldVal)
            {
                oldVal.Increment();
            }
            return oldVal;
        });
    }

    public void Analyze()
    {
        foreach (var key in _storage.Keys)
        {
            if (_storage.TryGetValue(key, out var item))
            {
                //how to read it properly?
                long ticks = item.ModifiedTicks;
            }
        }
    }
}

public class ThreadSafeItem2
{
    private long _modifiedTicks;
    private int _counter;
    public void Increment()
    {
        //no interlocked here
        _modifiedTicks = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
        _counter++;
    }

    //now interlocked here
    public long ModifiedTicks => _modifiedTicks;
    public int Counter => _counter;
}
```

**2.** use `Interlocked` and `memory barriers` on property level without lock, looks a bit verbose for me.

```
public class ThreadsafeService1
{
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, ThreadSafeItem1> _storage = 
        new ConcurrentDictionary<string, ThreadSafeItem1>();

    public void AddOrUpdate(string name)
    {
        var newVal = new ThreadSafeItem1();
        _storage.AddOrUpdate(name, newVal, (key, oldVal) =>
        {
            //no lock here
            oldVal.Increment();
            return oldVal;
        });
    }

    public void Analyze()
    {
        foreach(var key in _storage.Keys)
        {
            if(_storage.TryGetValue(key, out var item))
            {
                //reading through interloacked
                long ticks = item.ModifiedTicks;
            }
        }
    }
}

public class ThreadSafeItem1
{
    private long _modifiedTicks;
    private int _counter;
    public void Increment()
    {
        //make changes in atomic manner
        Interlocked.Exchange(ref _modifiedTicks, DateTime.Now.Ticks);
        Interlocked.Increment(ref _counter);
    }

    public long ModifiedTicks => Interlocked.Read(ref _modifiedTicks);
    public int Counter => Thread.VolatileRead(ref _counter);
}
```

What is the best practices here?

Comment: I think it depends on what `Analyze` does with those values. With second approach right after you read `long ticks = item.ModifiedTicks` this value might already be stale (another thread might have already updated it after you read). Depending on how you use those values it might be a problem or not.

Comment: @Evk I compare it with some threshold and decide: should I remove it from dictionary or not. Additionally in work project I have one more method in ThreadSafeItem which returns bool value based on counter and modifiedticks values.

Comment: So if you only increment modified ticks and you remove items based on "ModifiedTicks > threshold" - you don't care about "stale" ticks value. On the other hand if you remove based on "ModifiedTicks < threshold" then it's a problem, because after you read `ModifiedTicks` another thread might have increased it. In that case you would need to lock around whole operation (reading and removing). If you are not sure - lock around whole operation. Locking over just read itself makes little sense usually.

Comment: @mtkachenko Evk is quite right.  Since you're modifying the data that you're synchronizing based on the data you're getting out, that whole operation is logically part of a critical section.   You should just use a `Dictionary`, rather than a `ConcurrentDictionary`, and lock around both the entire operation to update the value as well as the entire operation to analyze that value.  Neither of your current solutions are safe, for numerous reasons.

Comment: @Evk This background check is scheduled to run every 10 minutes and it's ok for me read it and make decision - should i delete it or not. If some thread will update it a bit later, it's just too late. I only want to be sure that I read and write properties in item in consistent and thread safe manner.

Comment: @Servy I use `ConcurrentDictionary` because all items are independent and I don't want to lock entire dictionary to remove some objects.

Comment: @mtkachenko And yet you don't have anything else that you can lock on and still have a working solution.  Theoretically you could do something like create another dictionary of objects to lock on, but that would almost certainly be more work than it would save, and would use up a lot of memory.

Comment: @Servy I didn't catch your point. I suppose for me such situation is ok: read item from dictionary, check its timestamp, based on result of check define whether I should delete it from dictionary or not. If timestamp will be modified by another thread in few next nanoseconds after I read it for comparison - it's not a problem.

Comment: @mtkachenko If that's the case then your two solutions still have problems, but you can still get by using a `ConcurrentDictionary` if used properly.  I'll write something up.

Answer (score 1):

So both of your implementations have major problems.  The first solution locks when incrementing, but doesn't lock when reading, meaning the other places accessing the data can read invalid state.

A non-technical problem, but a major issue nonetheless, is that you've named your class `ThreadSaveItem` and yet it's not actually designed to be accessed safely from multiple threads.  It's the *callers* responsibility, in this implementation, to ensure that the item isn't accessed from multiple threads.  If I see a class called `ThreadSafeItem` I'm going to assume it's safe to access it from multiple threads, and that I don't need to synchronize my access to it so long as each operation I perform is the only thing that needs to be logically atomic.

Your `Interlocked` solution is problematic in that you have to fields that you're modifying, that are conceptually tied together, but you don't synchronize their changes together, meaning someone can observe a modification to one and not the other, which is a problem for that code.

Next, your use of `AddOrUpdate` in both solutions isn't really appropriate.  The whole point of the method call is to add an item or replace it with another item, not to mutate the provided item (that's why it takes a return value; you're supposed to *produce a new item*).  If you want to go with the approach of getting a mutable item and mutating it, the way to go would be to call `GetOrAdd` to either get an existing item or create a new one, and then to mutate it in a thread safe manner using the returned value.

The whole solution is radically simplified by simply making `ThreadSafeItem` immutable.   It lets you use `AddOrUpdate` on the `ConcurrentDictionary` for the update, and it means that the only synchronization that needs to be done is the updating of the value of the `ConcurrentDictionary`, and it already handles synchronization of its own state, no synchronization needs to be done at all when accessing `ThreadSafeItem`, because all access to the data is *inherently* thread safe because it's immutable.  This means that you never actually need to write any synchronization code at all, which is exactly what you want to strive for whenever possible.

And finally, we have the actual code:

```
public class ThreadsafeService3
{
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, ThreadSafeItem3> _storage =
        new ConcurrentDictionary<string, ThreadSafeItem3>();

    public void AddOrUpdate(string name)
    {
        _storage.AddOrUpdate(name, _ => new ThreadSafeItem3(), (_, oldValue) => oldValue.Increment());
    }

    public void Analyze()
    {
        foreach (var pair in _storage)
        {
            long ticks = pair.Value.ModifiedTicks;
            //Note, the value may have been updated since we checked; 
            //you've said you don't care and it's okay for a newer item to be removed here if it loses the race.
            if (isTooOld(ticks))
                _storage.TryRemove(pair.Key, out _);  
        }
    }
}

public class ThreadSafeItem3
{
    public ThreadSafeItem3()
    {
        Counter = 0;
    }
    private ThreadSafeItem3(int counter)
    {
        Counter = counter;
    }
    public ThreadSafeItem3 Increment()
    {
        return new ThreadSafeItem3(Counter + 1);
    }

    public long ModifiedTicks { get; } = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
    public int Counter { get; }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible here to have any problems with GC because of very intensive memory allocation?

Comment: @mtkachenko Feel free to profile the code and see if you're running into performance problems as a result of using this solution.  Once it's made immutable, the object would merit some consideration for being a value type; if your profiler resulted in demonstrable evidence that the additional allocations were causing enough additional GC pressure to be a problem (I highly doubt that will be the case, but it's not impossible) then you could look into making `ThreadSafeItem` a value type; it's certainly work as one.  I wouldn't mess with it unless there was a measured problem though.

Answer (score 0):

The solution proposed [by Servy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47076515/11178549) (using an immutable `Item` type) is probably the best solution for your scenario. I would also suggest switching from `class` to [`readonly struct`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/struct#readonly-struct) for reducing the allocations, although the `ConcurrentDictionary` is probably going to [wrap the struct](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/75408bbe8c67d9ffeb5427744ba34b3aac55b6a8/src/libraries/System.Collections.Concurrent/src/System/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentDictionary.cs#L562) in a reference-type `Node` internally, so you might not gain anything from this.

For the sake of completeness I will propose an alternative solution, which is to use the [`GetOrAdd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.getoradd) instead of the `AddOrUpdate`, and `lock` on the `Item` whenever you are doing anything with it:

```
public class Item // Mutable and thread-unsafe
{
    public long ModifiedTicks { get; private set; }
    public int Counter { get; private set; }

    public void Increment()
    {
        ModifiedTicks = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
        Counter++;
    }
}

public class Service
{
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, Item> _storage = new();

    public void AddOrUpdate(string name)
    {
        Item item = _storage.GetOrAdd(name, _ => new());
        lock (item) item.Increment(); // Dont't forget to lock!
    }

    public void Analyze()
    {
        foreach (var (key, item) in _storage.ToArray())
        {
            lock (item) // Dont't forget to lock!
            {
                long ticks = item.ModifiedTicks;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This solution offers probably the best performance, but the burden of remembering to lock correctly everywhere cannot be underestimated.

Answer (score -2):

I can't comment on the specifics of what exactly you are doing, but interlock and Concurrent dictionary is better than locks you do yourself.

I would question this approach though. Your data is important enough, but not so important to persist it? Depending on the usage of the application this approach will slow it down by some degree. Again, not knowing exactly what you are doing, you could throw each "Add" into an MSMQ, and then have an external exe run at some schedule to process the items. The website will just fire and forget, with no threading requirements.

Comment: Clients call this api a lot so I make some pre-aggregation in memory before put it to database.

Comment: Based on this, you will not run into any scaling or performance issues if you use a queue to aggregate it then put it in the database. It can also transactional with the database.

Comment: This service has client library which "make scalability".

Comment: Using any thread locks, will NOT make any application scale. You are telling all threads to stop and wait until until the operation is completed. Using Interlock and Concurrent Dictionary is just doing it better than you can do manually.

Comment: @acivic2nv Threads are only stopping and waiting when there is contention.  In the vast majority of situations, locks are not highly contexted, and thus have virtually zero performance impact.  Additionally, `ConcurrentDictionary` uses locks too, it just uses them as infrequently as is feasible.  Likewise, `Interlocked` has it's own overhead in cases of high contention.  But of course all of that is irrelevant until you have a working solution.  *Both* of the OP's solutions aren't actually safe.  The only *correct* solution is to lock around the entirety of both operations.

Comment: It doesn't matter how performant a solution is *when it produces the wrong result*.  Once you have a *working* solution, *then* you can consider performance.  As the OP's requirements involve critical sections that involve way more than just incrementing a single variable, `Interlocked` doesn't help, as it doesn't synchronize the multiple operations that need to be logically atomic with respect to each other.  Likewise, `ConcurrentDictionary` doesn't help because the critical sections are more than just single operations performed on the dictionary.

Comment: If either of those tools *would provide proper synchronization for the situation at hand* then by all means, using them would be preferable, because they're written by experts to do the jobs they're designed to do efficiently and correctly, and your custom code is less likely to be either.  But *when the problem you are trying to solve isn't solved by the designed use cases for either of those tools* then you can't use them.